# Zoom region and display as a subplot within plot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Is it possible to zoom into a region and display it as a subplot within the same plot? Here is my primitive attempt at freehand graphics, to illustrate my question:

[image]

I can think of using `Plot`, and then `Epilog`, but then I get lost in the positioning and in giving the plot its own origin (When I try `Epilog` on `Plot`, the new plot lays on top of the old one, using the old one's origin).

Also, it would be nice if the positioning of the subplot can be input, as different curves have different "empty regions" that can be used to position the image.

I've seen this in several articles and I can do this in MATLAB, but I have no clue how to do it in mma.

Comment: Perhaps this will interest you http://web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php look at the zooming section

Comment: Dead link: web.ift.uib.no/~szhorvat/mmatricks.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Inset.  Here's an example:

```
f[x_] = Sum[Sin[3^n x]/2^n, {n, 0, 20}];
x1 = x /. FindRoot[f[x] == -1, {x, -2.1}];
x2 = x /. FindRoot[f[x] == -1, {x, -1.1, -1}];
g = Plot[f[x], {x, x1, x2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
   Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None];
{y1, y2} = Last[PlotRange /. FullOptions[g]];
Plot[Sum[Sin[3^n x]/2^n, {n, 0, 20}], {x, -Pi, Pi},
 Epilog -> {Line[{
     {{x2, y2 + 0.1}, {-0.5, 0.5}}, {{x1, y2 + 0.1}, {-3.5, 0.5}},
     {{x1, y1}, {x2, y1}, {x2, y2 + 0.1}, {x1, y2 + 0.1}, {x1, 
       y1}}}],
   Inset[g, {-0.5, 0.5}, {Right, Bottom}, 3]},
 PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 _Since Version 4.0 (released in 1999), FullOptions has been superseded by AbsoluteOptions_. :D

Comment: For that matter, I wonder why I didn't just use Options?  Old habits die slowly, I guess.

Comment: Nice example! But it is probably better to use `Prolog` instead of `Epilog` in such cases for not overlapping the original graph.

Answer (score 7):

And, borrowing from [belisarius' code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412970/zoom-region-and-display-as-a-subplot-within-plot/5413570#5413570), you can also select the focus of your inset **interactively** by selecting a position at the x-axis:

```
imgsz = 400;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin@x, Abs@x > .1}, {Sin[100 x], Abs[x] <= 0.1}}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 5}}, 
  ImageSize -> imgsz, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Plot[f[y], {y, p[[1]] - .3, p[[1]] + 0.3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
     Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> imgsz/3], {1.5, 3}]],
 {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

or, if you also want to place the inset interactively:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 5}}, 
  ImageSize -> imgsz, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Plot[f[y], {y, p[[1, 1]] - .3, p[[1, 1]] + 0.3}, 
     PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
     ImageSize -> imgsz/3], p[[2]]]],
 {{p, {{0, 0}, {1.5, 3}}}, Locator, Appearance -> None}]
```

**EDIT**

one more alternative based on dbjohn's question:

```
imgsz = 400;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin@x, Abs@x > .1}, {Sin[100 x], Abs[x] <= 0.1}}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-2, 5}}, 
  ImageSize -> imgsz, 
  Epilog -> 
   Inset[Plot[f[y], {y, p[[1]] - .3, p[[1]] + 0.3}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
     Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> imgsz/3], 
    Scaled[zw]]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}, {{zw, {0.5, 0.5}, "Zoom window"}, Slider2D}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 good solution. @Sjoerd C. de Vries Using this I noticed that moving the inset and then clicking the plot will "jump" the inset when you really want the inset x axis focus to change, that is they sometimes get mixed up. Any suggested improvements to work around this? Maybe a second locator...

Comment: @dbjohn Yep, I noticed that as well. The click always goes to the nearest locator. This may mean that clicking on the curve can move the  zoom window if it was nearer than the  point on the curve that you zoomed previously. I thought of using modifier keys or so (ctrl-click etc) but that would make it more complex than I was prepared to do for the moment. Another solution might be a 2D slider to select the position of the zoom window.

Answer (score 6):

Just a kickstart:

```
imgsz = 400;
f[x_] := Piecewise[{{Sin@x, Abs@x > .1}, {Sin[100 x], Abs[x] <= 0.1}}];

Plot[f[x], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-5, 5}}, 
 ImageSize -> imgsz, Epilog ->
  Inset[Plot[f[y], {y, -.3, 0.3}, PlotStyle -> Red, Axes -> False, 
    Frame -> True, ImageSize -> imgsz/3], {3, 3}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find this an area in need of better built in tools. I have been working on this solution based on a demo [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/InsetPlotMagnifier/). I prefer to have the zoomed image and unzoomed image separated and as a bonus I added a presentable area where one could put relevant text or equations. For different functions the aspect ratio may need to be tweaked manually.

```
(f[x_] := x^2;
 ; xMin = -5; yMin = -5; xMax = 5; yMax = 5; 
 Manipulate[
  Grid[{{LocatorPane[{a}, 
      Plot[f[x], {x, xMin, xMax}, 
       PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax }, {yMin, yMax}}, 
       ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]], 
     Plot[f[x], {x, (a[[1]]) + xMin*mag, (a[[1]]) + xMax*mag}, 
      PlotRange -> {{(a[[1]]) + xMin*mag, (a[[1]]) + 
          xMax*mag}, {(a[[2]]) + yMin*mag, (a[[2]]) + yMax*mag}}, 
      ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}], 
     Item[StringForm["This is a suitable area to put any text.
       Value of A is :
       `1` ", a], Alignment -> {Left, Top}]}}, Frame -> All, 
   ItemSize -> All, 
   Spacings -> 5], {{a, {0, 0}}, {xMin, yMin}, {xMax, yMax}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> 
    Graphics[{Yellow, Opacity[.2], 
      Rectangle[Scaled[{.5 - (mag/2), .5 - (mag/2)}], 
       Scaled[{.5 + (mag/2), .5 + (mag/2)}]]}]}, {{mag, .5, 
    "Magnification"}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}])
```

[image]

```
(f[x_] := 
   Piecewise[{{Sin@x, Abs@x > .1}, {Sin[100 x], Abs[x] <= 0.1}}];
 ; xMin = -3; yMin = -3; xMax = 3; yMax = 3; 
 Manipulate[
  Grid[{{LocatorPane[{a}, 
      Plot[f[x], {x, xMin, xMax}, 
       PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax }, {yMin, yMax}}, 
       ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]], 
     Plot[f[x], {x, (a[[1]]) + xMin*mag, (a[[1]]) + xMax*mag}, 
      PlotRange -> {(*{(a[[1]])+xMin*mag,(a[[1]])+xMax*
        mag},*){(a[[2]]) + yMin*mag, (a[[2]]) + yMax*mag}}, 
      ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
      Frame -> True], 
     Item[StringForm["This is a suitable area to put any text.
       Value of A is :
       `1` ", a], Alignment -> {Left, Top}]}}, Frame -> All, 
   ItemSize -> All, 
   Spacings -> 5], {{a, {0, 0}}, {xMin, yMin}, {xMax, yMax}, Locator, 
   Appearance -> 
    Graphics[{Yellow, Opacity[.2], 
      Rectangle[Scaled[{.5 - (mag/2), .5 - (mag/2)}], 
       Scaled[{.5 + (mag/2), .5 + (mag/2)}]]}]}, {{mag, .06, 
    "Magnification"}, 0.01, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}])
```

[image]